# Understanding releasing resources

Tags: java, netty

I'm using Netty for handling HTTP request/response. And writing down to a pipeline the following ByteBuf:

```
public class MyBusinessLogic 
extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg){
        ByteBuf bb = ctx.alloc().buffer().writeBytes(//some bytes)
        ctx.writeAndFlush(bb, ctx.newPromise())
        //I did not release bb here
    }
}
```

In logs I got some warning similar to "`ByteBuf was garbage collected before it was released`"... something similar to it.

The question is why do we need to release `ByteBuf`s by ourselves? They are garbage collected anyway. What kind of bad troubles I can get into if I don't release the `bb` here?

Is it correct to just add buffer releasing as a channel future listener?

```
ByteBuf bb = //
ctx.writeAndFlush(response, ctx.newPromise())
.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener(){
   public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture f){
       buf.release()
   }
});
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326821/severe-leak-bytebuf-release-was-not-called-before-its-garbage-collected-ne https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805270/leak-bytebuf-release-was-not-called-in-before-its-garbage-collected-spring. Maybe this: https://logz.io/blog/netty-bytebuf-memory-leak/ would be worth a read (not my site, just from some google result)

Comment: @RC. I just looked at the answer. I'm interesting in a little bit more details. What can cause the memory leak if the `ByteBuf` is being garbage collected anyway?

Comment: Only 1% of all ByteBufs have leak detection turned on for performance, so 99% of the memory will leak by default: http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html#leak-detection-levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html:

> Since Netty version 4, the life cycle of certain objects are managed by their reference counts, so that Netty can return them (or their shared resources) to an object pool (or an object allocator) as soon as it is not used anymore. Garbage collection and reference queues do not provide such efficient real-time guarantee of unreachability while reference-counting provides an alternative mechanism at the cost of slight inconvenience.

This isn't the full blown explanation however. Netty ByteBuf can also have access to direct HEAP memory. This memory is special in the kind that this does not run the garbage collector when it gets full, and instead throws an exception.

The reason Netty tries to access the heap memory is basicly because this gives large speed increments when working with anything that works with "channels", like copying things from a file to a socket, or from socket 1 to socket 2. This has far better performance than doing the same thing with arrays, where the lower level first needs to convert it to a java array, and then back again when sending the packet.

Because of the way heap (direct) memory works together with the garbage collector, it may mean that in certain cases when the only object that is created are Netty ByteBufs, the heap memory gets full between invocations of the garbage collector, since from the point of view from the garbage collector, the memory was never full in the first place. Because of this quark in the garbage collector, Netty basically had to make a release method so memory was released directly when it was no longer needed.

Comment: Just dug into the source of `UnpooledHeapByteBuf`. `release()` method ends up in calling the so called `UnpooledHeapByteBuf::freeArray` which is actually `NO-OP`.

Comment: Btw, what about releasing the ByteBuf when operatio is complete in `ChannelFutureListener`? Is it the correct way or it has some drawbacks?